# OS X Arduino 1.6.8 CLI MainClassNameRequired

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

Whenever I try to run any Arduino CLI commands, I am always getting a popup saying "MainClassNameRequired". What is going on and what do I need to do to be able to run arduino CLI commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following JA.SO question and answer: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/20667.
My Japanese is *terrible*, and Google Translate didn't help too much, but the paths in the answer were correct and I was able to get the gist & get it working.

It turns out that, for whatever reason, the Arduino symbolic link created in /usr/local/bin, even though it is linked to the correct executable, doesn't actually pass the parameters through.

The Japanese answer suggested two solutions, both of which work. Firstly, remove the existing symlink from /usr/local/bin, then you can either:

- Create a shell script wrapper to call the Arduino executable that will pass parameters through and then link create a symlink to that (or just make it executable and place it in /usr/local/bin):

  `#!/bin/bash
   exec /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/MacOS/Arduino "$@"`

  `ln -s /usr/local/bin/arduino arduino.sh`
- Create an alias

  `alias arduino='/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/MacOS/Arduino`

Now when you execute `arduino` from your command prompt, your parameters are correctly passed to the program.